# dictionary_in_python select a item

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am doing the following dictionary:

```
import random

from tkinter.messagebox import YES

name = input("Hello, what is your name? ")
print("nice to meet you {}!".format(name))

instruments = (["Bass","Guitar","Piano"])

instruments1 = ({"Name":"Bass","Price":"US$ 900,00"},
               {"Name":"Piano","Price":"US$ 1000,00"},
               {"Name":"Guitar","Price":"US$ 900,00"})

print("{} we have these instruments for you to buy:".format(name),", ".join(instruments))
#the line above give m all items without the brackets

answer = input("You're going to take some of them? Yes or no.")#waiting the user input

if answer == YES:#boolean command for confirming the yes/no answer. 

    print("{} which one will be?".format(name))
    pos_awnser = input()
    print(pos_awnser,"It's a very good choice.")

elif awnser != YES:
    print("Sorry, we don't have what you need.")  
    print(pos_awnser,"costs",)
```

and I want to display the type of instrument that was chosen previously and display the name and price at the console

Comment: Thanks, I was in doubt about the join function for a sic.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it like that, create a single dictionary instead, like this

```
instruments = ({"Bass":'US$ 900,00',"Guitar":"US$ 1000,00","Piano":"US$ 900,00" })
```

You can then print the instruments using,

```
print("{} we have these instruments for you to buy:".format(name),", ".join(instruments.keys())
```

and display the type of instrument through

```
print(pos_awnser, instruments[pos_answer], " is a very good choice.")
```